# Conflict between boost:type_erasure and boost::iterator_facade

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iterators, boost-type-erasure

Consider this very simple program:

```
#include <boost/type_erasure/is_placeholder.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile with:

```
  include/boost/type_erasure/is_placeholder.hpp:31:33: error: reference to 'use_default' is ambiguous
    struct is_placeholder< ::boost::use_default> : ::boost::mpl::false_ {};
                                    ^
    include/boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp:44:18: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'boost::use_default'
    using iterators::use_default;
                     ^
    include/boost/type_erasure/is_placeholder.hpp:21:8: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'boost::use_default'
    struct use_default;
           ^
    1 error generated.
```

I don't want to go and change those header files. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Fails on 1.57, works with 1.55.

Comment: Is there a way to work around in 1.57?

Comment: This should simply be reported as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution would be replace

```
struct use_default;
```

in `boost/type_erasure/is_placeholder.hpp' with

```
namespace iterators {
    struct use_default;
}
using iterators::use_default;
```

Which is found in `boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp'.